# Connexion/Flask application: get base_path from request

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, connexion

I have a connexion/flask/werkzeug application and I need to be able to obtain the "base_path" during requests.  For example: my application is available at: http://0.0.0.0:8080/v1.0/ui/#/Pet, with the base_path being: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/v1.0".

I want to be able to get the base_path when the requestor performs any defined operation (GET, POST, PUT, etc).  I have not been able to find an easy way to obtain the base path.  Through a python debugger, I can see the base_path is available higher up in the stack but doesn't appear to be available to the application entrypoint.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import connexion
import datetime
import logging

from connexion import NoContent


PETS = {}


def get_pet(pet_id):
    pet = PETS.get(pet_id)

    # >>>--> I WANT TO GET THE BASE_PATH OF THE REQUEST HERE <--<<<

    return pet or ('Not found', 404)
```

For reasons I can not detail due to nda, I have multiple openapi specs for this application and it's important for me to know which base_path is being requested (as they are different).  If somebody could help me figure out a way to obtain the base_path per request I would be greatly appreciative :)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried use `connexion.request.base_url` ?  https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html#header-parameters you can access the connexion.request insider your handler

Comment: You are a godsend, this is perfect!  :). Thank you so much!

Comment: You welcome, pls mark this question as solved

Comment: I post the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `connexion.request.base_url` .
https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html#header-parameters you can access the `connexion.request` inside your handler

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [topic](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data) (**Incoming Request Data**) from `Flask` documentation

and `dump` the incoming `request` with the `before_request` hook and extract the right one e.g `request.base_url` for your case:

```
from flask import .., request

@bp.before_request
def dump_incoming_request():

    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(request.__dict__.items())
```